# Plot columns with row

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, plot

I would like to plot the five first columns of the matrix , how can I fix this code ? Thx

```
T = range(data.shape[0])


for i in range(data.shape[1],):

  plt.plot(T, (data[:, i]), label=f'n={i}')
```

Comment: Please, give us more details regarding the original data shape and the expected result so we can help you.

Comment: What is wrong with this code? It works perfectly fine for me (Plotting a `10x3` random array: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1GuQ.png). Please provide a [mre] that reproduces your problem, and a description of what the problem actually is. Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!